# Windows 7 Lenovo W530 Network Cable Unplugged

Tags: windows-7, networking, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo W530 with an Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network controller running windows 7.
So far I cannot figure out how to get it to connect to the local network it always says
"Network cable unplugged"

I downloaded the latest drivers, I flushed my DNS, I tested the cable on another machine
and still can't get this to work on my laptop.

Any other suggestions? or is it possible to tell if the NIC is just faulty?

Comment: Are you sure the cable works?  Have you tested it?

Comment: Yea its brand new and tested it on a coworkers machine.

Comment: What does the device manager say about this device?  Does it detect a device specific driver is installed?

Comment: It says "This device is working properly" and lists the driver as Intel 12.10.28.0 Date: 8/21/2013

Comment: any possibility that you have configured some settings inside the adapter properties?   I have had a similar issue after enabling jumbo packets on the onboard ethernet adapter on my desktop.   Not too sure why, but the machine simply wont get an IP address if I enable jumbo packets of any size in the adapter config..

Comment: Also, I would try to boot a live cd version of linux and see if you get the same results in Linux as you do in Windows.   If you see the same behavior, then your NIC is faulty :(

Comment: Uninstall your Nic card via device manager, reboot windows and it will "find new hardware" and reinstall it.